# what protocol does iChat use for its bonjour chat?

Tags: networking, bonjour, zeroconf, ichat

Please don't say bonjour. The best guess I can gather is XMPP, but I don't think thats right

Comment: Bonjour is only a service discovery protocol.

Comment: exactly, so what does it use to actually send messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iChat does use Bonjour (which is a multicast-DNS based service discovery protocol) to find other nodes when they're on the same LAN.  For remote chat it uses XMPP.

It uses SIP (and RTP?) for the actual chat and audio / video sessions.